# jQuery Flot line chart with month,year in x-axis

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, flot

I'm trying to generate a graph with month,year in x-axis. Please check below for ex:

[image]

The data for the graph is obtained via ajax. Please check below for sample json:

```
{"total":[[2013,4,0],[2013,5,0],[2013,6,0],[2013,7,0],[2013,8,0],[2013,9,0],[2013,10,475],[2013,11,0],[2013,12,0],[2014,1,367],[2014,2,0],[2014,3,0]],"critical":[[2013,4,0],[2013,5,0],[2013,6,0],[2013,7,0],[2013,8,0],[2013,9,0],[2013,10,0],[2013,11,0],[2013,12,0],[2014,1,1],[2014,2,0],[2014,3,0]],"high":[[2013,4,0],[2013,5,0],[2013,6,0],[2013,7,0],[2013,8,0],[2013,9,0],[2013,10,20],[2013,11,0],[2013,12,0],[2014,1,20],[2014,2,0],[2014,3,0]],"medium":[[2013,4,0],[2013,5,0],[2013,6,0],[2013,7,0],[2013,8,0],[2013,9,0],[2013,10,24],[2013,11,0],[2013,12,0],[2014,1,135],[2014,2,0],[2014,3,0]],"low":[[2013,4,0],[2013,5,0],[2013,6,0],[2013,7,0],[2013,8,0],[2013,9,0],[2013,10,42],[2013,11,0],[2013,12,0],[2014,1,26],[2014,2,0],[2014,3,0]]}
```

In the above example [2013,4,0] should translate to x-axis: Apr 2013, y-axis: 0.

Can you please let me know how i can achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's how I'd do it:

```
// your JSON
obj = {"total":[[2013,4,0],[2013,5,0],[2013,6,0],[2013,7,0],[2013,8,0],[2013,9,0],[2013,10,475],[2013,11,0],[2013,12,0],[2014,1,367],[2014,2,0],[2014,3,0]],"critical":[[2013,4,0],[2013,5,0],[2013,6,0],[2013,7,0],[2013,8,0],[2013,9,0],[2013,10,0],[2013,11,0],[2013,12,0],[2014,1,1],[2014,2,0],[2014,3,0]],"high":[[2013,4,0],[2013,5,0],[2013,6,0],[2013,7,0],[2013,8,0],[2013,9,0],[2013,10,20],[2013,11,0],[2013,12,0],[2014,1,20],[2014,2,0],[2014,3,0]],"medium":[[2013,4,0],[2013,5,0],[2013,6,0],[2013,7,0],[2013,8,0],[2013,9,0],[2013,10,24],[2013,11,0],[2013,12,0],[2014,1,135],[2014,2,0],[2014,3,0]],"low":[[2013,4,0],[2013,5,0],[2013,6,0],[2013,7,0],[2013,8,0],[2013,9,0],[2013,10,42],[2013,11,0],[2013,12,0],[2014,1,26],[2014,2,0],[2014,3,0]]};

// reformat into the format flot likes
seriesData = [];    
for (var prop in obj) {
    // push in the series, the "property" is the label
    // use $.map to produce an array of [date, y-value]
    // the new Date(i[0],i[1]-1).getTime(), 
    // will give you the epoch time for the first day of that month/year
    seriesData.push({label: prop, data:$.map(obj[prop], function(i,j){
         return [[new Date(i[0],i[1]-1).getTime(), i[2]]];
    })});    
}

// plot it!
$.plot("#placeholder", seriesData, {
    xaxis: { mode: "time", timeformat: "%b %Y" }
});
```

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/yT464/23/).

Edit: It was changed `j` by `i[2]` in order to display the data correctly plotted.

Answer (score 2):

In the options:

```
xaxis: {mode: "time", timeformat: "%b %m"}
```

Using the [time plugin](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data).

The data has to be converted to timestamps as explained in the link. As you have 0 in the day, maybe something like:

```
tstamp = new Date(dat[0]*1000*3600*24*30*12+dat[1]*1000*3600*24*30)
```

Comment: Hi,  Since i'm obtaining json from ajax call, how can i convert it to timestamp?

Comment: Make an array from "total" calculating each value converting to miliseconds and changing to timestamp like I showed for `tstamp` and use the values for the x-axis. Don't forget to add mode and timeformat to the options under xaxis and to include the `jquery.flot.time.js` script.